# How I can hide bottom sheet using behavior?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, behavior

I want hide bottom sheet in loading Activity in first time.

And then when I click the button, show the bottom sheet.

So I set like this,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout_BottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        android:background="@drawable/mappoint_edge"
        >
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

}
```

and when click the button,

```
private void setButton() {

if (!state){
        bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }else{
        bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }


}
```

But I have some issue in this.

When I put `bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)` in `onCreate`, bottomSheet never show even if click, but I when delete it, bottomSheet hides and show by click.

If I want hide the bottomSheet in first time, where I place the `bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)`?

If you know about it, please reply

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Inside your `onClick()` of the button use: `sheet.show()`.

Then when you want dismiss it, use `sheet.dismiss()`;

```
private void setButton() { 
    if (!state){ 
        bottomSheet.show() 
    }else{ 
        bottomSheet.dismiss() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote the answer as correct if you solved your iaaue or do let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: I can't see `show()` or `dismiss()` in `BottomSheetBehavior`

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate`,

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

And when I show it,

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```